# Access array key with space

Tags: handlebars.js

How can i access an array key with a space?

Standard way,

```
{{MyArray.name}}
```

Key with space,

```
{{MyArray.first name}}  or {{MyArray['first name']}}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: With Mustache 2.2.1 it actually works for me with `{{MyArray.first name}}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use brackets in conjunction with dots, without quotes:

{{MyArray.[first name]}}

Answer (score 8):

Here is the syntax:

```
{{[First Name]}}
```